# Min(), Max() within date subset

Tags: oracle, range, max, min

Not sure if the title fits, but here's my problem:
I have the following table:

```
create table OpenTrades(
AccountNumber   number,
SnapshotTime    date,
Ticket          number,
OpenTime        date,
TradeType       varchar2(4),
TradeSize       number,
TradeItem       char(6),
OpenPrice       number,
CurrentAsk      number,
CurrentBid      number,
TradeSL         number,
TradeTP         number,
TradeSwap       number,
TradeProfit     number  
);
alter table OpenTrades add constraint OpenTrades_PK Primary Key (AccountNumber, SnapshotTime, Ticket) using index tablespace MyNNIdx;
```

For every (SnapshotTime, account), I want to select min(OpenPrice), max(OpenPrice) in such a way that the resultimg min and max are relative to the past only, with respect to SnapshotTime.
For instance, for any possible (account, tradeitem) pair, I may have 10 records with, say, Snapshottime=10-jun and openprice between 0.9 and 2.0, as well as 10 more records with SnapshotTime=11-jun and openprice between 1.0 and 2.1, as well as 10 more records with SnapshotTime=12-jun and openprice between 0.7 and 1.9.
In such scenario, the sought query should return something like this:

```
AccountNumber  SnapshotTime  MyMin   MyMax
-------------  ------------  -----   -----
1234567        10-jun        0.9      2.0
1234567        11-jun        0.9      2.1
1234567        12-jun        0.7      2.1
```

I've already tried this, but it only returns min() and max() within the same snapshottime:

```
select accountnumber, snapshottime, tradeitem, min(openprice), max(openprice) 
from opentrades 
group by accountnumber, snapshottime, tradeitem
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [analytic versions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm) of `min()` and `max()` for this, along with windowing clauses:

```
select distinct accountnumber, snapshottime, tradeitem,
  min(openprice) over (partition by accountnumber, tradeitem
    order by snapshottime, openprice
    rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as min_openprice,
  max(openprice) over (partition by accountnumber, tradeitem
    order by snapshottime, openprice desc
    rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as max_openprice
from opentrades
order by accountnumber, snapshottime, tradeitem;

ACCOUNTNUMBER SNAPSHOTTIME TRADEITEM MIN_OPENPRICE MAX_OPENPRICE
------------- ------------ --------- ------------- -------------
      1234567 10-JUN-14    X                    .9             2 
      1234567 11-JUN-14    X                    .9           2.1 
      1234567 12-JUN-14    X                    .7           2.1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/645e4/1).

The `partition by` calculates the value for the current `accountnumber` and `tradeitem`, within the subset of rows based on the `rows between` clause; the `order by` means that it only looks at rows in any previous snapshot and up to the lowest (for `min`) or highest (for `max`, because of the `desc`) in the current snapshot, when calculating the appropriate min/max for each row.

The analytic result is calculated for every row. If you run it without the `distinct` then you see all your base data plus the same min/max for each snapshot ([Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/645e4/2)). As you don't want any of the varying data you can suppress the duplication with `distinct`, or by making it a query with a `row_number()` that you then filter on, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. It looks as if that did indeed answer my need. I should definitely get more familiar with Oracle's analytic functions...

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your problem ?

```
select ot1.accountnumber, ot1.snapshottime, ot1.tradeitem,
       min(ot2.openprice), max(ot2.openprice)
from opentrades ot1, opentrades ot2
where ot2.accountnumber = ot1.accountnumber
  and ot2.tradeitem = ot1.tradeitem
  and ot2.snapshottime <= ot1.snapshottime
group by ot1.accountnumber, ot1.snapshottime, ot1.tradeitem
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply; however, it seems this query is taking forever to execute; I'll look at the results when they come up...